# Error Dotspatial featureset

Tags: c#, dotspatial

Writing code using C# and the DotSpatial library, with the following code:

```
FeatureSet fs = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Polygon);
        fs = FeatureSet.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\\MapFile\\Land.shp");
```

I get this error message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'DotSpatial.Data.IFeatureSet' to 'DotSpatial.Data.FeatureSet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: i dont know whether i am missing a cast..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var featureSet = FeatureSet.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\\MapFile\\Land.shp")
```

DotSpatial loads shape files by default.

Answer (score -1):

```
fs = (FeatureSet)FeatureSet.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\\MapFile\\Land.shp");
```

Comment: Please include a bit more info about where and how to use, and perhaps even explanation about why this would work.